# Salesforce External Credentials Custom Body

Tags: security, namedcredentials, accesstoken, externalcredentials

I was configuring external credentials in Salesforce, but I noticed, there's no Custom Body on it, is there any way to add it using OAuth 2.0 Authentication Protocol? I'm only seeing Custom Headers but there's no Custom Body. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you select "Pass client credentials in request body" in the External Credential, then any headers will be passed as a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" body, including the Client ID and Secret from the Principal and any custom headers you define -- see example screenshot below using a Named Credential and External Credential to authenticate with PandaDoc.

Here's [another relevant thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow).

[image]

Comment: Upvoted your answer for mentioning an important nuance. The question is vague and may not mean what you think it means. (The term "Custom Body" makes no sense in oAuth). As for your answer - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding is going to be used by EC/NC _for the request body_ regardless of whether you check the _Pass creds in body_ option. The option controls how the creds are stuffed into the request: via Authorization header or in body.

Comment: We updated [our Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow) to cover this. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: We tried to use the answer above, selecting the 'Pass client credentials in request body', but it does not seem that the custom headers(outside of client creds) are sent in the request body.