# How to use HTTP Callout action in Flow with body of Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: visual-workflow, httppost

I am trying to setup an authorization step using the HTTP Callout feature in FLOW.

The authorization endpoint I am getting my token from needs to receive the body payload as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. As far as I can tell I am only able to provide a JSON body in the action when setting it up.

**EDITED TO ADD AN EXAMPLE OF HOW I CURRENTLY GET THE TOKEN:**

Currently I have an APEX class like below which I call to get a new token but I would like to use the HTTP Callout action in flow instead. I am also using Named Credential here to hold my endpoint and External Credential to hold my persisting OAuth tokens which are updated by another class if the token is no longer valid.

```
public class MyAPIGetToken {
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Token' description='Get authorization bearer token for MyAPI')
    public static List<OutputVariables> getToken(){
        
        String validity = 'VALID';
        String status;
        Integer statusCode;
        
        if (!MyAPITokenHelper.checkTokenValidity('MyAPIServices')) {
            
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            
            req.setEndpoint('callout:MyAPIAuthorization/oauth2/v2.0/token');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={!$Credential.MyAPIAuthorization.client_id}&client_secret={!$Credential.MyAPIAuthorization.client_secret}&scope={!$Credential.MyAPIAuthorization.scope}');
            
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            
            MyAPITokenResponse tr = (MyAPITokenResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), MyAPITokenResponse.class);
            DateTime dt = System.now();
            DateTime expires = dt.addSeconds(tr.expires_in);
            
            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {
                MyAPITokenHelper.updateToken('MyAPIServices', tr.access_token, expires);
                validity = 'VALID';
            } else {
                validity = 'INVALID';
            }
            
            status = res.getStatus();
            statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
        }
        
        List<MyAPIGetToken.OutputVariables> outputs = new List<MyAPIGetToken.OutputVariables>();
        MyAPIGetToken.OutputVariables output = new MyAPIGetToken.OutputVariables();
        output.validity=validity;
        output.status=status;
        output.statusCode=statusCode;
        outputs.add(output);
        
        return outputs;
        
    }
    
    public class OutputVariables {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Validity' description='Validity of the access token')
        public String validity; 
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='Response Status' description='Status message returned for the response')
        public String status; 
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='Response Status Code' description='Value of the status code returned in the response')
        public Integer statusCode; 
    }
    
}
```

How would I reproduce the above in an HTTP Callout within a Flow?

I have already created other FLOW actions to GET and POST data to other APIs as well but those just use query parameters in the path or a JSON payload body.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. The token would be acquired via a Named Credential (NC), the flow prompts you to provide one. See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/use-external-services-with-a-flow/register-external-service for an example.

Comment: @identigral Thanks for the reply. I looked through the article you referenced. I am familiar with External Services and Named Credentials as I am already using them for persisting OAuth Tokens with callouts through APEX and other HTTP Callouts in Flow that accept a payload body in JSON. My specific use case doesn't seem to be documented anywhere and may not be supported at this time. I will try to add additional detail to me question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External + Named Credential with oAuth client credentials flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow)

Comment: @identigral, I have seen that question and it does not. That is HTTP Callout through APEX, I need HTTP Callout through Flow.

Comment: Are you using [HTTP Callout Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5) in your flow? It relies on Named Credential for token acquisition. Give it a shot, you might be surprised.

Comment: I just spoke with Salesforce support and they confirmed that there is no way to define the body payload as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded when using the HTTP Callout action in Flow. They did share that this is likely going to be on the product roadmap, and I will share more detail here as they share it with me. For now the only way to do this is to define the HTTP Callout in APEX as shown in the details of my question above..

Comment: Works for us with a Flow and HTTP Callout - see our updated example linked above.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can able to send the request with content-type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' using HTTP Flow POST action.
For that you just need to manually update the External service created for your POST action.

For every HTTP Post Action using Flow, salesforce creates an external service and apex class to define and validate the request and response body schema. Go for the External services in Setup and find your HTTP post action related external service,. Just edit and update the content of request body as like below. By default it would be 'application/JSON'.

[image]