# Callout failed for invocable action

Tags: callout, namedcredentials, visual-flows, http

I'm trying to set up a FLOW with an HTTP Callout **"GET"** request and I'm getting the below exception.

Info

> Error Occurred:
>
> Callout failed for invocable action
> GetProspectLinkedinSearchTest.GetProspect Linkedin Search Test. We
> couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required
> permissions, or the external credential
> "GetProspect_Linkedin_Search_Test" might not exist.

I've added the named credential to the permission set. Still, I'm getting the exception.

[image]

[image]

Here is the Request Template

> url
> 'https://api.getprospect.com/public/v1/insights/contact?linkedinUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2'
>
> --header 'accept: application/json' 
> --header 'apiKey: f5bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

I've no clue why I'm getting this issue

Comment: Missing permissions, see step 3 in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow

Comment: Already i have provided through permission sets

Comment: Please edit your question and show that - see [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does the running user have R and View All on `UserExternalCredential` SObject?

Comment: I have provided the access through permission set. Still getting the same issue

Comment: But if I tried with a similar kind of setup with external services it worked like a charm. But I'm getting issues with HTTP callout.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.

The issue was resolved by assigning read permission on the "User External Credentials" in the "Object Settings". You can assign this directly in your permission set.

Reference: https://www.infallibletechie.com/2022/03/the-callout-couldnt-access-endpoint-you.html