# Proposal for Ensuring Clean Data in SFMC: Email Address Validation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

We've identified a significant number of email addresses in our SFMC org that have been bounced or suppressed due to List Detective. To ensure a clean and accurate database, we have recently cleansed our data. However, to maintain ongoing data quality, I am exploring the implementation of a process that selectively brings only validated data into SFMC.

Currently, our data originates from Salesforce CRM, and I'm considering collaborating with the Salesforce team to incorporate email address validation checks before creating a contact. The idea is to utilize the SFMC API for email address validation – a process where contact creation in SFMC will only proceed if the validation response is positive.

I've come across the documentation regarding email address validation in SFMC using the API, which can be found here: Link to Salesforce Marketing Cloud Email Validation Documentation.

I would appreciate your insights on this approach and welcome any alternative suggestions or best practices to ensure the ongoing cleanliness and quality of our SFMC data.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: The approach makes sense and is certainly possible. Ultimately though, if you want true quality and cleanliness - you’ll have to consider something you didn’t mention, double opt in.

Comment: See our comments in  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow/40948