# Programatically give a user access to an ExternalCredential Principal (Per User)

Tags: apex, oauth2, oauth, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I try to find a way to programatically give a user access to an ExternalCredential Principal (Per User).

The standard way, is to go to personal settings and click "Allow Access".

I found out that clicking the button, is a redirection to an url that is built with the url returned from this method :

```
ConnectApi.OAuthCredentialAuthUrl output = 
   ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getOAuthCredentialAuthUrl(input);
```

However, I don't find an easy to create a redirect in an apex class. (not in a vf page).

I was thinking that the method : `createCredentials` will do the job, but I don't find detailed explanations about it.

Is someone already did that ?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Access to External Cred is granted via Profile or Perm Set - see [example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow)