# External/Named Credential - acquiring access token from Mule via client credentials flow

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, mulesoft, externalcredentials

I want to configure Named&External Credentials with oAuth client credentials flow and use it in apex.
An endpoint is exposed by Mulesoft. I followed those very neat instructions shared [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/409485/145367), but I get CalloutException without any error description when I run my code:

**apex code**:

```
        String inputBodyString = JSON.serialize(inputDetails);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:e_api/stage/dosomething/withdata');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(inputBodyString);
        req.setTimeout(30000);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
```

**Logs:**

```
07:22:26.90 (106240722)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[31]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=callout:e_api/stage/dosomething/withdata, Method=POST]
    07:22:26.869 (869720369)|UNKNOWN|NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=null, Named Credential Name=null, Status Code=0, Content-Type=null, Response Size bytes=0, Overall Callout Time ms=0, Connect Time ms=0
    07:22:26.90 (870171998)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[31]|System.CalloutException: Unable to fetch the OAuth token. Error: . Error description: .
```

**Raw callout to obtain the token:**

```
    curl --location 'https://api.foobarsitename.com/stage/v1/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "client_id": "02f63eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0bc0",
    "client_secret": "561XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX06029",
    "grant_type": "CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"
}'
```

**Raw second callout to get desired info:**

```
curl --location 'https://api.foobarsitename.com/stage/dosomething/withdata' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer q2lGCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXh1BDBw' \
--data '{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5"
}'
```

**External Credentials:**

[image]

**Principal details:**

[image]
**Named Credentials:**

[image]

I already tried to turn off and on all checkboxes with no success. I think all is set up correctly, but still am not sure whether this type of REST API is good to be used with NC/EC. Thank you in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Your config looks correct. In your curl attempt, the value of `grant_type` must be lowercase (`client_credentials` rather than `CLIENT_CREDENTIALS`) according to oAuth spec. EC/NC will send in lowercase. If Mulesoft wants uppercase, it could be that...but you'd probably get a more legible error message if this was the case (pun fully intended).  Assuming that changing the case doesn't help, open a support case (pun^2, yeah)

Comment: Upvoted your question for including all details, including curl repro. Excellent effort for your first question, welcome to SFSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer therefore I share it with you. There were two issues in this case. Both were solved on the mulesoft side.

1. Mulesoft expected **"grant_type"="CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"** and received **"grant_type"="client_credentials"**. As @identigral mentioned in the answer above, this is Salesforce default and can not be changed.
2. Mulesoft expected **Content-Type: application/json** for token request. Salesforce sends token request with **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. This is Salesforce default and can not be changed.

Mulesoft developer aligned connection structure on his end. The alignment helped and the connection is now successfully working!