# Setup Name Credential with External Credentials

Tags: api, namedcredentials

I'm starting developing on Salesforce, and I've to send some data to one of our client api. The client gave some access details to connect to their webapi.

It looks like this :

```
url POST 
https://mywebapi.com/v1/test

Authentification 
grant type : password credential

Access token url 
https://myaccesstoken.com/test/oauth2/token

username
myusername@test.com

Password
xxxyyyzzz

client id
urn:oauth:webapi:test:webapi

client secret
aaabbbccc
```

I tried this :
[image]
But I see no where where I can enter all the info provided by the client.

Even on the  legacy section I can't find where to enter all those infos.
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Assuming your client is referring to Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type -> it is outlawed by oAuth spec, is a poor security practice and not recommended. Thus, it's not supported out of the box (at least in a no-code fashion) by Named/External Cred.  You can still code it in Apex. There are many Q&As on this topic here - do a search.

Comment: Thank you, what may I suggest to my client to provide to us?

Comment: For server-to-server, [Client Credentials](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow) or [JWT Bearer](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5)