# Named Credential / External Credential Only Working Once

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

I've used a Named Credential with External Credential for the Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow.

I didn't find the documentation very helpful to be honest, but this super post helped me get it working: [External + Named Credential with oAuth client credentials flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow)

My issue now is this only works once, which is bizarre. Then I need to edit the Principal record making a change (which is adding the Client ID and Secret, even though they are already there) and then saving it. The token returned for me here last for 4 hours. However I assumed each time I made the callout it would get a new token? Just to be clear I'm only testing via Apex Anonymous to make the callout, but don't think that's the issue. Once authenticated, I can make multiple callouts without an issue.

**Example when working:**

[image]

**Example when not working:**

[image]

So the way I'm interpeting this is that it's not getting the token each time?