Validate an email in Marketing Cloud using APIs

I'm going through this page of the documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_address
And it says is for validating an email in such way:
Validates email addresses to reduce the likelihood that sending an email to an address results in a bounce or spam complaint.
Now what exactly is checking? Is there any extra reference about it? What's the benefit to do this check with each email I would send it? When is recommended to use it?
I already do a pre validation before create a subscriber, so I'd like further details about this API request to understand it better
Thanks

See the bottom of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow

This endpoint can help you validate whether an email address meets certain criteria. The checks you can perform can be either or a combination of:

SyntaxValidator: Validates that the email address includes a name, an
at sign (@), and a domain. E.g. hello@john@example.com would fail this check, due to multiple occurrences of "@"
MXValidator: Validates that a DNS mail
exchange (MX) record exists on the domain of the email address. E.g. you might have a domain which seems valid, e.g. restapirocks.com - but the lack of MX records there, make it impossible for it to receive emails.
ListDetectiveValidator: Validates the email address by using List
Detective, a proprietary database of email addresses that are known
to be invalid or inactive (this is based on anonymously collected data across all Marketing Cloud accounts)

My preferred use case for this endpoint is to utilise it in a front-end form validation. E.g. if someone wants to sign up using john.doe@example.com, this would be prevented, as this endpoint returns MXValidator error, prompting user to provide a correct email address.
The use case for this endpoint once an email address is in SFMC is limited, as email addresses are automatically "scrubbed" against ListDetective at the time of send. You can read more about ListDetective here.
